# extracting data from HTML Pivot table

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, iframe, html-table

I have a couple problems i am trying to solve:  
1. Columns 1-3 could be merged cells thus missing 'td' values, how can i populate each row if the td doesn't exist for these columns? Alternatively, columns 4-7 always are visible.  One way i was thinking about handling this would be to loop backwards to get column 7, 6, 5, 4, and if column 3, 2, 1 do not exist to use prior value from prior row 
2. In column 4, there could be multiple values and one or more hyperlinks.  I need to extract the text and all hyperlinks to click on them and download the attached files.

If there is a better method other than selenium, please let me know.  Final output is to have this data table and attachments populate into an excel file.

Python - Selenium code: This code works to extract each row of data by each column within the HTML code ('td')

```
table = driver.find_element_by_id('table')  
row = table.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
for rows in row: 
    cols = rows.find_element_by_tag_name("td")
    for col in cols:
        print(col.text)
```

I have attached the HTML code that I extracted using Beautiful Soup to give you an idea what the table looks like. The first table row has 7 'td' but subsequent rows do not.   [image: HTML Code]

ok. So i have made the following improvements to the col code.  Reversing the loop worked perfectly! Now all my hyperlinks will always be in column 4.  Now i have to figure out columns 1-3 to populate for every row and opening all of the hyperlinks and saving them to a specific folder on share drive.  Thanks!

```
    columncounter = 7
    cols = rows.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
    for col in reversed(cols):
        print('ColumnNumber = %d' %columncounter)
        print(col.text)
        if columncounter == 4:
            colfour = col.get_attribute('innerHTML')
            colfour2 = col.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
            for a in colfour2:
                print(a.get_attribute('href'))
    columncounter-=1
```

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely not the best solution, but here is what i did to get this to work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from win32com.client as win32

xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = 1
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open('Template.xlsx')
xl.DisplayAlerts = False
ws = wb.Worksheets('Sheet1')
tr = 10   # paste results into row 10 for excel table
for rows in row[1:] #skip header row
    rtxt = rows.text.strip()  #trim text to determine if row is empty
    if rtxt:   # used to determine if rtxt variable for empty row
        columncounter = 7
        cols = rows.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
        for col in reversed(cols):
            if columncounter == 7:
                col7 = col.text
            elif columncounter == 6: 
                col6 = col.text
            elif columncounter == 5:
                col5 = col.text
            elif columncounter ==4: 
                col4 = col.text
                colfour = col.get_attribute('innerHTML') #get entire cell code
                colfour2 = col.find_elements_by_tag_name('a') 
                for a in colfour2:
                    link = a.get_attribute('href') #extract hyperlink
                    linkh = 'https'
                    if linkh in link:  #only want hyperlinks that start with https
                        for i in link:
                            col8+=i     #extracts multiple link into same variable
            elif columncounter == 3:
                col3 = col.text
            elif columncounter == 2:
                col2 = col.text
            elif columncounter == 1:
                col1 = col.text
            columncounter-=1
        #paste all of the values in column into excel
        dest_cell = ws.Range('A' + str(tr))    
        dest_cell.Value = col1
        dest_cell = ws.Range('B' + str(tr))    
        dest_cell.Value = col2
        dest_cell = ws.Range('C' + str(tr))    
        dest_cell.Value = col3
        dest_cell = ws.Range('D' + str(tr))    
        dest_cell.Value = col4
        dest_cell = ws.Range('E' + str(tr))    
        dest_cell.Value = col5
        dest_cell = ws.Range('F' + str(tr))    
        dest_cell.Value = col6
        dest_cell = ws.Range('G' + str(tr))    
        dest_cell.Value = col7
        dest_cell = ws.Range('H' + str(tr))    
        dest_cell.Value = col8  
        tr+=1   
    else:
        continue   #skip empty rows
```

This will append columns 1-3 values, since there are no 'td' values for all 7 columns for every row because of merged cells in first 3 columns.  Then paste each value into excel file as duplicative values until it gets to new value retrieved from col.text for that column based upon columncounter.